# Single Player Commands "java.lang.StackOverflowError"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, mods, minecraft-mods

I am using Single Player Commands to assist me while making a map. I am trying to use the `/butcher` command (this kills all mobs near the player), but I keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
```

I am not sure what the problem is.

Also my computer specifications can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/hMMpsRj6).

Comment: Are you running Minecraft with the default amount of RAM?  If so, you should try increasing it and see what that does for you.

Comment: I have 4GB allocated to Minecraft. I have 8GB of ram.

Comment: Is any more information included in this error?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Here is a screenshot to show: http://i.imgur.com/2q2NL4k.png

Comment: That's probably *too much* RAM, and certainly way more than Minecraft usually needs. You might be starving other processes for memory, but I don't see how that could cause a stack overflow…

Comment: No log files in your minecraft folder that might have a stack trace?

Comment: SevenSidedDie: well I just want to be able to work underwater without 20 bloody squid getting in my way constantly. I think I'll post this error in the thread where I got it from.

EDIT: what log files would I looking for? any specific name?

Comment: You mentioned too much ram? well if I have 8GB how much should I be allocating to it?

Comment: Is WorldEdit installed on a server or as a mod? Also, try reporting the bug on the bug tracker (http://youtrack.sk89q.com/issues/WORLDEDIT) for WorldEdit.

Comment: @MBraedley Increasing the RAM allocation won't really help with a `StackOverflowError`, increasing it doesn't affect the stack frame size. You could try launching with the `-Xss2048k` flag set, which sets the JVM's per-thread stack frame size to double it's default value. Generally though this is a band-aid solution, and may not even help if the code responsible is doing something really stupid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech  support for nodded Minecraft. We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can try, here is what I would try if I were in your shoes:

Make sure that the versions of your mods and minecraft match up - are you playing on Minecraft v1.5.0 but using World Edit 1.5.1?

If you are using the proper version of everything, try these commands and seeing if you get the same error (please don't be surprised if any of these spit out an unknown command error to you) :

> //butcher
>
> /butcher 50
>
> //butcher 50

Where the **50** represents the radius around you, meaning any mobs within a 50 block radius will be killed.

If that still doesn't work, try **forceupdating** your minecraft, then installing SinglePlayerCommands on your clean minecraft.jar.

There might be other mods, such as ones that add in new blocks, or even mobs, which might be interfering with you. So make sure to check (that if you are using these other mods) that you have compatible versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to force update Minecraft, it's a bug with a Java loop. If Minecraft works, make sure, that you downloaded the latest (1.5.2) singleplayer commands (automated installation is better). If it doesn't works, try to install manually (and delete the Meta-inf)!

Comment: "It's a bug with a Java loop": that sounds like you're referring to a known bug, that is maybe documented somewhere? If so, could you provide a link, or more background? Just something so that a reader can better judge the veracity of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Overflow error is caused when the program goes out of the bounds of an [array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type) (a type of storage that can store multiple values all alongside each other). Since each array has a specific length, what has happened is that Single Player Commands has gone over the limit of one of its arrays.

The cause of this could be because you are trying to slaughter too many animals at the same time, so try just butchering mobs in a small area at the beginning and see how that works out.

This command will do this for you:

```
//butcher 20
```

Which will destroy all animals in a radius of 20.

Comment: No, if you go out of bounds of an array you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. `StackOverflowException`s are generally caused by a dodgy recursive method call or set of cyclical method calls causing the stack to overflow.